# problems in torch.hub.load()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, environment

I' using the following script on a python notebook:

This is the class

```
class yolov5l6_ti_lite_640(ObjectDetector):

        def __init__(self, dictionary):
                super().__init__()
                self._params_ok = self._checkparameters(dictionary)

        def _checkparameters(self, dictionary):

                passed_flag = False

                try:
                        self._model_dir = dictionary['model_directory']
                        self._desired_classes = dictionary['desired_classes']
                        self._min_conf = dictionary['min_conf'],
                        self._model_url = dictionary['model_url']
                        passed_flag = True
                except KeyError as ke:
                        log.error(f"Wrong parameters provided: {ke}")
                
                return passed_flag

        def load_model(self):
       # Provide the URL for the YOLOv5 model's weight file
              
                # Load the YOLOv5 model
                self._model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path= '/Users/marco.vinciguerra/Bitbucket/sam/segmentator_proposal/classes/models/Yolov5l6_ti_lite_640/best.pt', force_reload=True)
```

This is where I call the method

```
yolov5l6_ti_lite_640_model = yolov5l6_ti_lite_640(dict)
yolov5l6_ti_lite_640_model.load_model()
```

the problem is when i run pyhton notebook it works, but when I use .py files I have the following problem:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/marco.vinciguerra/Bitbucket/sam/segmentator_proposal/yolov5_l6.py", line 16, in 
yolov5l6_ti_lite_640_model.load_model()
File "/Users/marco.vinciguerra/Bitbucket/sam/segmentator_proposal/classes/yolov5l6_ti_lite_detector.py", line 40, in load_model
self._model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path= '/Users/marco.vinciguerra/Bitbucket/sam/segmentator_proposal/classes/models/Yolov5l6_ti_lite_640/best.pt', force_reload=True)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 555, in load
repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, trust_repo, "load",
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 222, in _get_cache_or_reload
_validate_not_a_forked_repo(repo_owner, repo_name, ref)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 181, in _validate_not_a_forked_repo
response = json.loads(_read_url(Request(url, headers=headers)))

How can I solve it?

I tried to run both the scripts with the same environment

Comment: Please format the errors appropriately so that they are legible. Also it's not clear what you mean by this "I tried to run both the scripts with the same environment". What scripts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.